# How to send message to a specific user by using gmail Api

Tags: php, gmail-api

For sending gmail message first i create a draft then send it. I create successfully the draft but i can't find a way to specify the To parameter (to whom this message is going to be send)

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

put the recipient in the To, Cc, or Bcc header.

Comment: can you show me an example where to put the recipient in the To header. My code look like this:

Comment: $message = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message(); $message->setRaw(base64_encode($text)); 
$draft = new Google_Service_Gmail_Draft();
$draft->setMessage($message);                                       try {

     $draft = $service->users_drafts->create($profile->username, $draft);
     
  $service->users_drafts->send($profile->username, $draft);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
     print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

Comment: @GlobalEnterprise Edit your question with the code instead.

Comment: I'm trying to reply to a message by using gmail api. Can you show me an example how to do it?